# String representation of an object in Python

Tags: python

So in the book([Problem Solving with Algorithms and Data Structres](http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Graphs/Implementation.html)) that I'm currently using as a reference, this is how a graph is implemented. What I don't understand here is how exactly the `__str__` function in the class `Vertex`works here and why we need it. Can anyone please explain? Thank you!

```
 class Vertex:
     def __init__(self,key):
         self.id = key
         self.connectedTo = {}

     def addNeighbor(self,nbr,weight=0):
         self.connectedTo[nbr] = weight

     def __str__(self):
         return str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])

     def getConnections(self):
         return self.connectedTo.keys()

     def getId(self):
         return self.id

     def getWeight(self,nbr):
         return self.connectedTo[nbr]




 class Graph:
     def __init__(self):
         self.vertList = {}
         self.numVertices = 0

     def addVertex(self,key):
         self.numVertices = self.numVertices + 1
         newVertex = Vertex(key)
         self.vertList[key] = newVertex
         return newVertex

     def getVertex(self,n):
         if n in self.vertList:
             return self.vertList[n]
         else:
             return None

     def __contains__(self,n):
         return n in self.vertList

     def addEdge(self,f,t,cost=0):
         if f not in self.vertList:
             nv = self.addVertex(f)
         if t not in self.vertList:
             nv = self.addVertex(t)
         self.vertList[f].addNeighbor(self.vertList[t], cost)

     def getVertices(self):
         return self.vertList.keys()

     def __iter__(self):
         return iter(self.vertList.values())
```

Answer (score 3):

the `__str__` function is what's called when you attempt to stringify the object, so

```
g = Vertex(key)
print str(g) # calls __str__
```

this can be implemented to make printing objects easier

Answer (score 3):

One line of code would have sufficed to ask your question:

```
str(self.id) + ' connectedTo: ' + str([x.id for x in self.connectedTo])
```

Let's pick that apart:

1. `self.id` is the unique ID of your object. `str()` converts that to a string.
2. we concatenate `connectedTo:` and then the
3. `str()` conversion of a list as generated by the `[...]` construct.

I guess 3.  is giving you problems. It's just a central Pythonic construct and selects every element in the `self.connectedTo` sequence, takes `.id` of that and returns a list of these.

After that, you have a string, that `__str__` returns. Since that method is called whenever python tries to get a string form of an object, it might be called when you do something like

```
print Vertex
```